# What does "its windows" refer to in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

**The Sorcerer's Stone** (J.K. Rowling 1997, Ch. 6, pg. 83)

> The narrow path had opened suddenly onto the edge of a great black lake. Perched atop a high mountain on the other side, **its windows** sparkling in the starry sky, was a vast castle with many turrets and towers.

'It' is used when we mention what we had just said in the previous sentence, so I thought 'it' here means a mountain because there's nothing else that can be 'it' in 'Perched atop a high mountain on the other side'.

But what is 'mountain's windows' then? Does a mountain have windows?

Comment: It's bad form not even to credit the author in your question. You can understand the sentence more easily if you arrange the clauses differently: **_"A vast castle with many turrets and towers was perched atop a high mountain on the other side with its windows sparkling in the starry sky."_** ...or... _**"A vast castle with many turrets and towers, its windows sparkling in the starry sky, was perched atop a high mountain on the other side."**_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this passage, the "it" refers to the vast castle. Notice how the dependent clause (perched atop a high mountain on the side) makes the subject of the sentence clear, in that the subject is something that's perched on top of a mountain.